# how to prevent the DataGridView column increasing

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a DataGridView. I am binding the DataGridBiew with a datasource as below...

```
  private void form_load(object sender, eventargs e)
  {
         var members = xyz.members(..
                         select new {
                            blah....
                               blahh...
                             });
         memberbindingsource.datasource = members
         membergridview1.datasource = memberbindingsource;

         // at here i have added button column to membergridview 1 
         // like this....
         DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
         membergridview1.Columns.Add(column);
         column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
         column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
         column.Text = "ADD";
         column.HeaderText = "Add";
         column.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
         column.Name = "btnadd";
```

this works fine at form load but somewhere I check the conditions in the combobox like this

```
            if(combobox1.text == "abc")
            {

                   then  i have to loaded the grid view again 
                    like this ...
                     var members = xyz.members(..
                         select new {
                            blah....
                               blahh...
                             });
                         memberbindingsource.datasource = members
                         membergridview1.datasource = memberbindingsource;

     at here i have added button column to membergridview 1 
        like this....
        DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
       membergridview1.Columns.Add(column);
        column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        column.Text = "ADD";
        column.HeaderText = "Add";
        column.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        column.Name = "btnadd";

      }
```

when is first select the  combobox1 text "abc"  the datagridview  was showing the button column thats fine ...

when I check the first conditon ( like this `combobox1.text == "abc"` ) the  DataGridView displaying details ok but if I check again the same condition it will again added the button column.

I want to show only one button column with members data when I check the same condition again and again.

How can I prevent this - not increasing the button column again and again?

Comment: so selecting an item from the combo box should add a new column, but only if it doesn't exist? Or are you asking something else entirely?

Comment: ya .. i have to check conditions like this up to 6 (conditions) so .. every time i have to populate the datagridview is there any way we can operations on binding source i mean can i use same binding source for  6 (checks) like that ...

Comment: This is very confusing. Why are you adding the column again every time the combobox text = "abc"? Just remove the code that re-adds the column if you don't want it added over and over.

Comment: @kevev22 at form load i have populated some data coming from database and i have added button column too. in that form i have combobox i have repopulate the gridview according to conditions in combobox( like this if member age is > 20 i want to show the members name and members age in  datagridview at the same time i want to show the button column also ....with the members data in datagridview ..... i have done like this if i am not added the button column in this checking conditions the button column will disappear thats not what i want ........

Comment: i want to show the button coulmn with checking conditions also my problem is i have added the button column with this checking conditions when i check the first conditon the grid view displaying details ok but if i check again the same condition it will again added the button column again........ i want to show only one button column with members data when i check the same condition again and again ....this is what i want .....

Comment: @kevev22 do u ahve any idea about this .....

Comment: To be honest, I think our biggest problem in solving your question is a language barrier.

Comment: trying to boil this down to the basics: So based on some user interaction, you want to add and or remove columns to the grid?

Answer (score 0):

This is because everytime your page loads you are adding this column. So no matter this is a fresh call or a post back call this column is added.
To get this work proper enclose the code snippet that adds the column in following if condition

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //add your column add code snippet here 

    }
```

so your code will look something like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn column = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
       membergridview1.Columns.Add(column);
        column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        column.Text = "ADD";
        column.HeaderText = "Add";
        column.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        column.Name = "btnadd";
    }
```

Comment: i  am not sure.. whether postback property is available in winforms....to i heard that it is available in webapps